# ggplot: show graph of response variable paired by specific variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a simple question, but I am trying to make a graph in ggplot and I am having a hard time trying to show the data in pairs according to the variable 'time'. My data looks like this:

```
id  season       sex    treatment   time    shift(Km)
1   Early dry   PRIDES  UNDISTURBED BEFORE  0.016
2   Early dry   PRIDES  UNDISTURBED BEFORE  0.016
3   Early dry   PRIDES  UNDISTURBED BEFORE  0.016
4   Wet         PRIDES  DISTURBED   AFTER   0.0972
```

I would like the final graph to have the exact layout as the graph below, but what I have not figure out yet is how to plot my response variable in pairs according to the variable 'time', that is, to show the before and after values paired for each 'treatment' group (disturbed/undisturbed), not on top of each other as it is showing in the graph below.

[image]

This is the code I have:

```
ex <- read.csv(file = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23723553/data.csv",
               header= TRUE, row.names =1)

ex$time <- relevel(ex$time, ref = "BEFORE")

ggplot(data = ex, mapping = aes(x = treatment,
                                        y = dist_shift.Km., 
                                        shape= time)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se) +
  facet_grid(season ~ sex)+
  labs(x= "\nTreatment", y = "Shift of centroids (m)\n")+
  theme_bw()
```

Could someone help me modify my code?

UPDATE: plotting the time/treatment interaction as suggested by @lukeA gets me closer to what I am aiming for, but graphing the interaction plots side by side 'disturbed before' with 'undisturbed before' and then 'disturbed after' with 'undisturbed after'. I would like to plot instead side by side: 'disturbed before' with 'disturbed after', and 'undisturbed before' with 'undisturbed after'.

[image]

And, is there a way to change the names in the x axis so I can have only 'disturbed' 'undisturbed' instead of 'disturbed.before' etc. The time before/after is already explained by the shape and described in the legend.

Many thanks!

Comment: Try `x = interaction(treatment, time)` instead of `x = reatment` - is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you Luke. It is closer to what I want but not quite. I have updated my question to explain this further.

Comment: Well, you could just change it to `x = interaction(time, treatment)` then and add a labeler function like `scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) sub(".*\\.", "", x))`. You probably also want to rotate the labels, e.g. `theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))`.

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I needed! Thank you! Do you know if there is a way to reduce the space between the pairs (e.g. disturbed before and disturbed after), so the before and after values for each treatment appear right next to each other, as a pairwise comparison? And do post your comment as an answer so I can accept it as such in my post. :)

Comment: Hmm to reduce the space, you could maybe use a continuous scale instead of a discrete one. But I guess that would make a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add argument `position=position_dodge()` to `stat_summary()` to place before and after values close to each other.

```
ggplot(data = ex, mapping = aes(x = treatment,
                                y = dist_shift.Km., 
                                shape= time)) +
      stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se,position = position_dodge(width=0.2)) +
      facet_grid(season ~ sex)+
      labs(x= "\nTreatment", y = "Shift of centroids (m)\n")+
      theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could for example do

```
ggplot(data = ex, mapping = aes(x = interaction(time, treatment),
                                        y = dist_shift.Km., 
                                        shape= time)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se) +
  facet_grid(season ~ sex)+
  labs(x= "\nTreatment", y = "Shift of centroids (m)\n")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) sub(".*\\.", "", x)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]